# In google analytics, how can I pass a device type and model through ecommerce tracking?

Tags: google-analytics

Basically, we use affiliate products.  When we get a return call from their servers saying we have a sale, we want to send that information back into GA.  Right now we can do that just by loading the page with ecommerce tracking and tacking on UTM parameters in the link based on the user who purchased...

One big thing we want to do though is actually send back the device information the user purchased with back to analytics.  we capture it in our custom CRM, I'm just not sure how we can pass it back to analytics.  using valuetrack parameters in the URL doesn't work, and i'm not sure how to modify the ecommerce code to figure this out.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Look for a browser extension that allows you to fake the user agent string (or hire a programmer to build a more convenient way to fake the ua string programmatically based on CRM input)